# How to add data table into legend in openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

How to use openpyxl to add data table into legend area like the pic show below:

There is a openpyxl.chart.chartspace.DataTable class in openpyxl, but I can't find any examples to use it.

[image: The final result I want to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but if someone needs it, I've found a solution.

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Series, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.plotarea import DataTable

# Create a new Workbook.
wb = Workbook()

# Select the active worksheet.
ws = wb.active

# Data
rows = [
    ('val', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2'),
    ('val_1', 10, 30),
    ('val_2', 40, 60),
    ('val_3', 50, 70),
    ('val_4', 20, 10),
    ('val_5', 10, 40),
    ('val_6', 50, 30),
]

# Adding data to worksheet.
for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)

# Create a new BarChart.
chart1 = BarChart()

# Adding some attributes.
chart1.type = "col"
chart1.style = 3
chart1.title = "Bar Chart"
chart1.y_axis.title = 'Test number'
chart1.x_axis.title = 'Sample length (mm)'

# Adding data and labels.
data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=7, max_col=3)
labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
chart1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart1.set_categories(labels)
chart1.shape = 4

# --- SOLUTION --- Creating the legend table.
chart1.plot_area.dTable = DataTable()
chart1.plot_area.dTable.showHorzBorder = True
chart1.plot_area.dTable.showVertBorder = True
chart1.plot_area.dTable.showOutline = True
chart1.plot_area.dTable.showKeys = True

ws.add_chart(chart1, "A10")

wb.save(".\\result.xlsx")
```

**--- RESULT ---**

[image]

> openpyxl version == 3.0.10

I hope I've been able to help! :D